# Dynamics NAV RTC : Command Line Parameter Passing

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-dynamics

I am currently developing a system that will allow for an external piece of software to click a button and his will then execute some c#.net code that plans to call the Dynamics NAV RTC by using the following code.

```
Process.Start("Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.exe");
```

The external application contains variables that I would like to pass through to the NAV CRM.

Is there a way that i could do this by Passing the parameters like what you would with a web address similar to the way below:

```
Process.Start("Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.exe",  "DynamicsNAV://localhost:7046/DynamicsNAV70/CRONUS%20UK%20Ltd./RunPage?Page=50000&amp;No=10");
```

The above line doesn't work. I receive the followowing error:

> Priming dictionary contains a key 'no' which is not allowed
>
> Parameter name: primingDictionary

Does anyone in the community know how I could produce this functionality in a similar way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use it like that:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.exe",
            "DynamicsNAV://localhost:7046/DynamicsNAV70/CRONUS%20UK%20Ltd./RunPage?Page=50000&amp;No=10");
Process.Start(psi);
```

the first argument is the process itself, the secomd is the argument.

you can change them as you'd like

you can learn on the argument NAV accept [here](http://dynamicsuser.net/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/vanvugt/4861.RTC_5F00_Startup_5F00_Parameters.JPG)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was initially vague with what my problem was. I have changed the question so if you know how i could solve the changed question that would be great.

Comment: @LiamHall what happen when you dismiss the no part?

Comment: This parameter passing works: "DynamicsNAV://localhost:7046/DynamicsNAV70/CRONUS%20UK%20Ltd./RunPage?Page=50000 however i get the error when i try to add a parameter. When i click ok on the error dynamics NAV CRM doesn't load.

Comment: it looks like it means Nav.Client doesn't accept that parameter... are you sure you need it?

Comment: Well i am looking for a way to pass parameters to NAV. I am not sure its supported. So i am asking to see if it can be done and whether or not anyone has experience of how to do it. Maybe i have been asking the question the wrong way?

Comment: @LiamHall i've edited the answer, hope it'll help you and i'll get accept :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just call the overload of `Process.Start()` that takes input arguments:

```
Process.Start("Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.exe", "DynamicsNAV://localhost:7046/DynamicsNAV70/CRONUS%20UK%20Ltd./RunPage?Page=50000&amp;No=10");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was initially vague with what my problem was. I have changed the question so if you know how i could solve the changed question that would be great.